# How to proof using only pumping lemma that something is not regular?

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

In formal languages I need to proof using the pumping lemma that the following is not regular:

$A_1=\{1^m0^n10^n|n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$

How to achieve that? Any help is upvotet

Comment: HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, start with the word $0^p10^p$.

Comment: An in this case important question: Is $0\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: yes 0 is part of N

Comment: @RayofCommand OK, in that case, Brian's hint helps. If we had $0\notin\Bbb N$ (or equivalently, if we impose a condition $m\ge m_0$ with $m_0\ge1$) it looks like the "normal" pumping lemma holds for this language even though it is not regular ...

Comment: thanks, that helped already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\mathcal L=\{1^m0^n10^n| m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ regular language?

**Hint:**

No, we will prove with the pumping lemma, let us choose the word $z=0^p10^p$

**Spoiler:**

> $\quad|z|>p$ So $z=uvw,\quad |uv|\leq p, \quad |v| \geq 1, \quad uv^iw\in \mathcal L \quad i\geq0$  For all $i\neq 1$ the word not in $\mathcal L$ because $u,v$ will be in the first zero's part or in the last zero's part or will be here: $00..\overbrace{..0100}^{u,v}000$